# How to convert long array to string array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am getting the checked items ids in `ListView` from `List.getCheckedItemIds` which returns `long` array, now how to convert this array to `String` array ?

```
long [] long_list = ProcessList.getCheckedItemIds();
```

Comment: It is hard to imagine you really tried anything before posting this here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String[] string_list = new String[long_list.length];

for(int i = 0; i < long_list.length; i++){
    string_list[i] = String.valueOf(long_list[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The question may be considered unwarranted a few years ago, but it's worth a new look now considering the recent progress in Java land with regards to the emerging **Stream API**.

Instead of relying on any third-party API, you can use the built-in **Stream API** for array operations in Java 1.8 and above.

You can now easily use

```
String[] yourStringArray = Arrays.stream(yourLongArray).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray();
```

And if your intention is to print `yourStringArray`, you can then convert it into a string using

```
String str = Arrays.toString(yourStringArray);
```

****
Lucky for us, `Arrays.toString()` operates on all types of arrays, so the whole thing can be simplified to just

```
String str = Arrays.toString(yourLongArray);
```

Isn't this cleaner?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils* like this:

```
String[] string_list = StringUtils.join(long_list, ",").split(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage apache's BeanUtils to do Array conversion without doing iteration by yourself like below.

```
Long[] longArrays= (Long[]) ConvertUtils.convert(stringArrays, Long[].class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or with Java 8+,

```
Object[] array = ...; // or i.e. Long[] array
String[] s = Arrays.stream(array).map(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new String array and pass the values of long array to the string array one by one:

```
String[] s=new  String[long_list.length];
for(int i=0;i<long_list.length;i++)
{
s[i]=String.valueOF(long_list[i]);
}
```

Sorry for the mistakes. I've updated the code.